# Facebook type ProgressBar on top of Listview

Tags: android-listview

how to display and hide the progress bar on top of listview same as facebook in which loader display while only pull the listview toward bottom and the size of progressbar (loader) is set according to how much size produce by pulling the listview toward botttom?